# What object does LocateRegistry.createRegistry() return?

Tags: java, rmi

I am fairly new to Java and I am wondering what is going on here.

There is a class RMIServer, which creates a new registry in it's constructor.

```
public class RMIServer {
    private static final int PORT_NUMBER = 1099;
    private Registry registry = null;

    public RMIServer() {
        registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(PORT_NUMBER);
    }
}
```

Now when I look in the `LocateRegistry` classes' `createRegistry()` method I can see that it returns an interface `Registry`

```
public final class LocateRegistry {

    private LocateRegistry() {
        // compiled code
    }

    public static Registry createRegistry(int i) throws RemoteException {
        // compiled code
    }
}
```

Usually I believe there should be a class returned, but even when I look at javadoc I am unable to find what class the object is that will be returned.

The code works like it should, and now I am just wondering: how does this work and what would be the best way to figure this out by myself? (Give a man a fish, ...)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/registry/LocateRegistry.html

Comment: There are many methods in Java than return an interface type, not just RMI methods. Obviously the actual object has a class type as well, but it isn't any of your business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source code of OpenJDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/rmi/registry/LocateRegistry.java), it returns an instance of `sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl` which is an internal class:

```
public static Registry createRegistry(int port) throws RemoteException {
    return new RegistryImpl(port);
}
```

The public Javadoc does not usually cover such internal classes, which may change from one implementation of the Java platform to another. So another JRE implementation may theoretically use a different class as the `Registry` implementation.

See [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html) for more details on such classes that start with `sun.*`.